# Magento - import product csv does not enable base image

Tags: magento-1.8

I could not enable the base image from CSV. I exported the working products csv from server and imported the same. But the base images are not enabled for all the products. Images are exist in correct path. I can enable the base image from admin panel.

But can't do it from import products csv file.

I updated the image path in **image & media_gallery columns and gallery** value as 1.
Please advice.